# Не могу запустить Java на компютере

Tags: java, настройки

У меня проблема в том, что никак не могу поставить себе Java на ПК.
Недавно решил себе переставить Java на новую версию, обновил и перестало работать. Потом переустановил заново, но так же. И когда полез через cmd узнать, что у меня там установлено, то мне выдало вот это:

```
C:\Users\vadim>Java -version  
Unrecognized option: ЦXmx512M  
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.  
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Как я понимаю, это из-за того, что настройки прописаны в кириллице почему-то.

Как поменять эти настройки, если даже в настройки Java зайти не могу.

Comment: Java - это что такое и где находится?

Comment: Вы запускаете какой-то `.bat`/`.cmd` файл с параметрами вместо `java.exe`?  Какие пути у вас прописаны в переменной окружения `PATH`?

Comment: Java virtual machine. Просто Java после установки не запускает Ничего. Ибо в настройках Джавы прописано вот это. А это, то что я скинул, то это просто в cmd я прописал Java -version, чтобы посмотреть что как у меня поставлено, а получается что поставлено на комп Ничего.

Comment: У вас имеется некий исполняемый файл, который и запускается по команде `Java` с испорченной опцией, это может быть как `.exe`, так и `.cmd` / `.bat` файл.  Проверяйте пути, указанные в переменной окружения `PATH` .

Comment: Но я ничего не запускал, я просто проверил версию Джавы через коммандрную строку. И так как в Джаве неправильно выставленые настройки, то я даже контрольную панель Джавы открыть не могу, чтобы поменять эти значения.